# What are the restrictions on std::map<K, V>::mapped_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, standard-library

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
  public:
  Foo() {}
  virtual ~Foo() {}

  void DoFoo() { cout << "Foo" << endl; }

  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  void operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};

int main() {
  map<string, Foo> m;
  m["Foo"].DoFoo();
}
```

Both g++ and clang++ fail compilation when they're using a `libstdc++` version earlier than 4.8. The exact error message clang++ spits out is:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:39:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:39:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:40:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/char_traits.h:40:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:121:35: error: call to deleted
>   constructor of 'Foo'
>
> : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
>
> ^ ~~~
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:267:14: note: in instantiation of
>   function template specialization 'std::pair,
>   Foo>::pair, void>' requested here
>
> return __pair_type(std::forward<_T1>(__x), std::forward<_T2>(__y));
>
> ^
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:467:29: note: in instantiation of
>   function template specialization
>   'std::make_pair, Foo>' requested here
>
> __i = insert(__i, std::make_pair(std::move(__k), mapped_type()));
>
> ^
>
> 21 : note: in instantiation of member function 'std::map, Foo,
>   std::less >, std::allocator, Foo> > >::operator[]' requested here
>
> m["Foo"].DoFoo();

It seems like `std::pair`'s constructor is trying to use `Foo`'s copy-constructor, which I guess is fair enough since `Foo` doesn't declare a move constructor. As I would expect, providing a (default) move constructor fixes the issue.

However, compilation succeeds without a move constructor defined when the version of `libstdc++` used is 4.8 or higher. I'm confident that the compiler is the same in both cases and only the `libstdc++` version varies. `Foo(Foo&&) = delete;` also doesn't affect clang's ability to properly compile in this case.

My question has a few facets:

Why does the old version of `libstdc++` require the move constructor to be user-provided in order to use it instead of the copy-constructor?

What's different in the newer version of the library that allows it to create the new element (as per `operator[]`'s contract) without any move/copy constructors or `operator=`?

Which of the implementation is conforming? What does the standard say about `std::map<K, V>::mapped_type`, if anything?

Comment: [Compiled fine here](http://cpp.sh/437p)

Comment: 23.2.4.7 has `The associative containers meet all the requirements of Allocator-aware containers (23.2.1), except that
for map and multimap, the requirements placed on value_type in Table 96 apply instead to key_type
and mapped_type. [ Note: For example, in some cases key_type and mapped_type are required to be
CopyAssignable even though the associated value_type, pair<const key_type, mapped_type>, is not
CopyAssignable. —end note ]` could be what is causing the issue.

Comment: @CoryKramer that seems to be using a recent `libstdc++`, which I know to be compiling fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I'll try to look around there! The note kind of points towards the newer version of `libstdc++` being less strict than the standard, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, [map.access] reads:

> `T& operator[](const key_type& x);`
>
> 1 *Effects*: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.
>
> 2 *Requires*: `key_type` shall be CopyInsertable and `mapped_type` shall be DefaultInsertable into
>   *this.
>
> 3 *Returns*: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
>
> 4 *Complexity*: Logarithmic.

The only requirement on `operator[]` on `mapped_type` is that it is DefaultInsertable (basically, DefaultConstructible). If the library doesn't support a non-copyable `mapped_type` with `operator[]`, then it's a bug.

Comment: @TemplateRex I'm trying to find the gcc bug for this but can't. It definitely fails on 4.7.2.

Comment: 4.7.2 is so old, it's eligible for cash for clunkers

Comment: Probably resolved with [44436](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436)